# Need help editing MongoDB document in Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

New mongoDb and somewhat Node js. I want to add strings of code into a document on Mongodb Atlas, where I have an array waiting to store these strings. I cannot seem to get the right code, nor can I find anything similar to my situation.

Ok, so I have seemed to achieve some progress with this issue. It will now update the array in mongo, but not in a good way. This is what running the server once does to the mongo document:

Before:

```
    _id:ObjectID("5c02199b1c9d440000266941")
Names:Array
```

After:

```
    _id:ObjectID("5c02199b1c9d440000266941")
Names:Array
--> 0:Array
    ---> 0:Array
         ---> Actual data
```

I am not sure why this is happening. This is the code which is producing these results:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser : true}, function(error, client) {
// perform actions on the collection object
var db = client.db("DatabaseTest");
    db.collection('Room').updateOne(
        {'Names':Array},
        {$push: {"Names": [queue]}},
        {}
    )

client.close();
});
```

Why is it adding 2 arrays instead of just adding to Names:Array?

Just solved it. It was a dumb mistake... I needed to remove the brackets from queue.

Comment: Read up on https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb For "collection.insertMany..."

Comment: Just updated my code. Turns out what I was looking for was collection.updateOne. Any ideas on what I can do to fix my problem? Thanks

Comment: Loop through the arrays and execute updateOne function... Unless there is a function in the mongodb package to insert all elements in an array

Comment: @AlqbalRaj Considered what you said and tried to implement it. I am still getting no errors, but the mongo array is not updating. Is there something wrong with the parameters? I will explain the names: Names is the name of the array in mongo. Songs is the name of the const which holds the array queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#append-multiple-values-to-an-array

If your `queue` variable is an Array, then you should rewrite your query like this:

```
var queue = [1, 2, 3, 4]

db.collection('Room').updateOne({
  { 'Names': Array },
  {
    $push: {
      Names: {
        $each: queue
      }
    } 
  }
})
```

Otherwise, if your `queue` variable contains a single value:

```
var queue = 5


db.collection('Room').updateOne({
  { 'Names': Array },
  {
    $push: {
      Names: queue
    } 
  }
})
```